# How to ignore local python when building python from source

Tags: python, configure

When I try to build my own version of Python using:

```
./configure --enable-shared --prefix=/app/vendor/python-dev && make && make install
```

I see some errors during installation:

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation
>   R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a
>   shared object; recompile with -fPIC /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a:
>   could not read symbols: Bad value

The problem starts when the linker tries to use `/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a` and not the newly compiled library.

How can I prevent the linker (configure/make) from using the python libraries installed on the system?

Comment: `./configure --enable-shared --prefix=/app/vendor/python-dev && make && make install` works for me (from the [Python-2.7.5 tarball](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.5/Python-2.7.5.tar.bz2) on Ubuntu 13.04). If the error occurs during the `make` part, you'll have to include the full output from `make`.

Comment: This is the only error. It simply repeats for other modules as well. I'm using 2.7.4 tarball. But I have 2.7.4 on my machine, compiled statically (I guess without -fPIC).

Comment: Sure, but the reason for the error will have happened much earlier in the build, so it's impossible to diagnose without more info. Take a look at [this](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2010-September/587427.html), and the followups. I'm not sure if it's the same issue, but there's not much more I can do without seeing the output from `make`.

Comment: Here is the log http://pastebin.com/ZBUp2cnd. And yes, the post mentions the same problem. But without a solution.

Comment: Did my solution work or not?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This looks to be a misfeature of the `setup.py` script always including `/usr/local` in the search path when `make` builds the target `sharedmods`.

You'll have to manually frob the `setup.py`, so do the...

```
./configure --enable-shared --prefix=/app/vendor/python-dev
```

...first, then edit `setup.py`, find lines 442, 443, and 444 which should look like this...

```
if not cross_compiling:
    add_dir_to_list(self.compiler.library_dirs, '/usr/local/lib')
    add_dir_to_list(self.compiler.include_dirs, '/usr/local/include')
```

...and comment them out so they look like this...

```
# if not cross_compiling
    # add_dir_to_list(self.compiler.library_dirs, '/usr/local/lib')
    # add_dir_to_list(self.compiler.include_dirs, '/usr/local/include')
```

...then the `make` should work.

Comment: The if statement need to be commented out as well. Otherwise parser would be expecting an indented block which is the two add_dir_to_list lines. Just for future reference.

Comment: i just met this issue when i was trying to recompile and reinstall python to /usr/local/lib again. In this case you have to use --prefix=/usr/local/lib again, and editing setup.py, as this answer suggests won't help. To fix it, I had to delete existing /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a file and /usr/local/lib/python2.7/ directory (maybe latter is not needed)

Answer (score 5):

I solved with [this script](http://toomuchdata.com/2014/02/16/how-to-install-python-on-centos):

```
# Python 2.7.6: 
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tar.xz
tar xf Python-2.7.6.tar.xz
cd Python-2.7.6
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-unicode=ucs4 --enable-shared       LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
make && make altinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

I just moved /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a to /tmp