# Error 'could not read symbols: Bad value' when installing Python

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

i need to install **mod_wsgi** for **Django**, but when i do `pip install mod_wsgi` i have an error:

```
    /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-LHF3wD/mod-wsgi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-lWmQhZ-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-LHF3wD/mod-wsgi/
```

So i found information about this problem and i tried to reconfigure python like this:

```
make clean
./configure --enable-shared
make
```

But now i have the same error after `make` command:

```
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

OS: CentOS 6,
python version: 2.7

Also i already have mod_wsgi for Python6.6 (by default. I installed "web server" version of centos)

What is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried with `sudo`? Maybe you don't have permissions

Comment: @Mr.E yes, i tried

Comment: but your error `'gcc' failed with exit status 1`. is gcc intalled?

Comment: @JavierClavero yes, gcc is installed, Python installation works fine without `--enable-shared`, but with this parameter i have the error...

Comment: you've tried  `make distclean`? and then `configure --enable-shared`

Comment: @JavierClavero yes, i tried it just now, unfortunately have the same error

Comment: What does `echo $CFLAGS` says?

Comment: @AlexeySmirnov it's -fPIC

Comment: you've tried with argument `--prefix=/usr/local`? (or path to installation python)

Comment: can you run python in cmd? Your path to python could be misconfigured

Comment: @GeorginaS yes, i can run python 2.7, it is installed now, but i need --enable-shared, but if i configure with it parameter it doesnt work, it shows me errors like this - `can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: could not read symbols: Bad value`. @JavierClavero i tried it now with `--prefix=/usr/local` but it still doesnt work

Comment: try running the command: ldconfig

Comment: @GeorginaS i run it, what should i do with it?

Comment: try install mod_wsgi again

Comment: @GeorginaS the same `/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against ` `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
    /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: could not read symbols: Bad value`

Comment: In this case it could be easier to not use pip and make mod_wsgi yourself. https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/wikis/QuickInstallationGuide.wiki should give you pretty much everything you need, just ensure you point to the correct version of python when compiling. I ran into nearly the exact same problem, but I was using python3.5 and pip3 instead.

Comment: mixing packages 32 and 64 bits. Try this, backup the file `mv /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so.backup` and then create symbolic link `ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py27.so /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so`

Comment: @GeorginaS this arcticle says "Python should preferably be available as a shared library." But the same error `can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: could not read symbols: Bad value` i have when install python with --enable-shared... So it make me insane :/

Comment: Yeah these errors are a real pain. Try running python from shell. import sysconfig, then run sysconfig.get_config_var('CCSHARED') does -fPIC come up?

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986952/how-to-ignore-local-python-when-building-python-from-source