# Issue installing lxml

Tags: python, pip, lxml

When I tried to install lxml using

```
pip install --upgrade lxml
```

..I am getting following error

```
/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-    
linux/4.7.2/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation     
R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making   
a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I could able to resolve it with solution here

[How to ignore local python when building python from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986952/how-to-ignore-local-python-when-building-python-from-source/16990281#16990281)

```
Python 2.7.6: 
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tar.xz
tar xf Python-2.7.6.tar.xz
cd Python-2.7.6
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-unicode=ucs4 --enable-shared               LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
make && make altinstall
```